# Eclipse git commit changes window doesn't appear

Tags: eclipse

When ever I commit a file in my project the commit changes window doesn't appear but instead focus is shifted to the git staging window. How do I get the commit changes window to appear again?
[image]

Comment: Timely. https://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/2016/05/16/git-staging-view/

Comment: @nitind is the timing of that post coincidence?

Comment: No idea, I just remember it from earlier in the day. Are you using Neon M7?

Comment: My "About Eclipse" says: Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Comment: Unexpected, but hopefully it had the answer you needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As nitind, this is mostly answered in this post:

https://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/2016/05/16/git-staging-view/

Answer (score 4):

Go to Preferences > Team > Git > Committing and uncheck "User Staging View to commit". Hola you will see your old favorite Commit Changes Window.